# missing .netbeans file netbeans won't install or unistall

Tags: file, netbeans, locking

So I had some computer problems and while trying to fix them I somehow deleted the .netbeans file. (src c://Users/{user}/.netbeans)
The short cut was deleted as well.  (I can't find them in the recycling bin)

I thougth I could re-install netbeans to get all the files re-built but the install wizard wont' install them because it sees that net beans is already installed.

So I tried uninstalling netbeans and it gives me a message saying that the Netbeans 7.3 file is Locked (I think this one was under AppData).  I don't believe this file is actually in use.

Any Ideas on where I can get a copy of the .netbeans file (or other ideas on how to fix this)?

and yes only a novice would somehow delete those files.